# Error while running 'Authorize an org'- command VS code (mac)

Tags: vs-code

- installed Vs code in mac
- installed java 11
- installed salesforce cli
- installed salesforce extension pack

ran the command "create project with Manifest' -- successfully ran.

ran the command 'Authorized an org'

**getting this error:**

Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org

20:43:45.24 sfdx org:login:web --alias triggerpractice --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
Warning: Ignoring extra certs from `null`, load failed: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
›   Warning: org login web is not a sf command.
Did you mean env log? [y/n]:
›   Error: Run sf help org for a list of available commands.
20:43:56.271 sfdx org:login:web --alias triggerpractice --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
ended with exit code 127

**what I have tried:**

in the terminal ran these commands

```
sfdx plugin:install @salesforce/plugin-auth@1.4.3
```

but not working.

can you tell me, if I have to set the path for 'sfdx cli' in mac; if yes, please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the CLI and it worked